# How to change (format) date output in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to format the date output in mySql to something like 01-DEC-1977, and I am ready to throw my computer because I just can't get it to work. this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE    myAuthor
(
ID      int(05) NOT NULL,
Full_Name   varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Birthdate   date,
Country           varchar(50) 
);
```

This is the data I am inserting:

```
INSERT INTO myAuthor(ID, Full_Name, Birthdate, Country)
values(1001, 'Bob Writer', 19770112, 'USA');
```

and this is what I am attempting thus far to do to format the date:

```
select 'ID', 'Full_Name', DATE_FORMAT('Birthdate','%d-%b-%Y') from myauthor;
```

When I do that the data comes out as null. this is the only thing I have managed to do that doesn't spit out an error or truncate the date all together.

Is there a way to format the date so that once entered it just comes out as DD-MON_YYYY, aand if not, how can I do this, or even better, what am I doing wrong? I have tried switching the date entered into insert where it is formatted with day, month and year, but I get an error when trying that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have single quotes and not back ticks around your column names, try:

```
SELECT ID, Full_name,DATE_FORMAT(Birthdate, '%d-%b-%Y') from myauthor;
```

Comment: Ug, now I feel like and idiot. I haven't used mySql in a while, been using Base to play around with SQL and it has me using the single quotes for columns, so i naturally just did that. Thank you sooooo much. I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: No worries, everytime I put something down and come back months later, something is either broken or of poor design.